# How to Build a login Image Slideshow background Like Pinterest App?

Tags: android, android-layout, background-image, android-animation, slideshow

I'm developing an app that has a login page for start. like the Pinterest app, I want to slide Random images smoothly in the background of login page Like the GIF below:

[image]

Can anyone have a Library or some code for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a Video, I think. So you can use a `VideoView` with some video asset.

If not, take at [this library](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView). With it you can get this like sliding `ImageView`, than connect `ViewPager` with `Runnable` to scroll pages every N seconds. There are many guides for making different transitions between `ViewPager` pages. Basicly you will have `ViewPager` with N pages, that will have layout with only one ImageView (KenBurns ImageView)

Comment: That's what I'm exactly looking for... Thanks @Ekalips